# How to remove fields from filebeat or logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat, logstash-configuration

I'm very new to ELK stack and i'm trying to process this log from a spring application.

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2021-02-17T18:25:47.646+01:00",
    "@version": "1",
    "message": "The app is running!",
    "logger_name": "it.company.demo.TestController",
    "thread_name": "http-nio-8085-exec-2",
    "level": "INFO",
    "level_value": 20000,
    "application_name": "myAppName"
}
```

On the machine where the Spring application is running i setup filebeat, that is connected to logstash.
Right now, the logstash configuration is this (very simple, very basic):

```
input {
   beats {
     port => 5044
     ssl => false
     client_inactivity_timeout => 3000
   }
}

filter {
   json {
      source => "message"
   }
}


output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => localhost
   }
}
```

I added the `json { source => "message"} }` to extract the message field from the log (i dont know if this is correct).
Anyway, filebeat is sending a lot of fields that are not included to the log, for example:

- agent.hostname
- agent.id
- agent.type
- and many other agent fields (version etc)
- host.hostname
- host.ip
- and many other host fields (os.build, os.family etc)

For my pourpose i dont need all this field, maybe i need some of them.. but for sure not all.

I'm asking how i can remove all this fields, and select *only* the fields i want. How i can do that.

And, to do this i think the right solution is to add a filter to logstash, so all the application (fielebeats) always send the entire paypload and a single instance of logstash will parse the message.. right ?

Doing this on filebeat means that i need to reproduce this configuration for all my application, and it's not centralized. But, because i started this new adventure yesterday.. i dont know if its right

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those fields under [agent] and [host] are being added by filebeat. The filebeat [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/defining-processors.html) explains how to configure them.